# What is the best way to remove an element from list and return a new list in C#

Tags: c#

For example:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = a.Remove(3);
```

Expected:
b = {1, 2} while a = {1, 2, 3}

Comment: Can you just clone it first, e.g. `var b = a.ToList(); b.Remove(3);`?

Comment: This is a very vague question. `Best` according to what criteria? You can clone the list and remove the item, you can create an [ImmutableList<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-5.0) which creates a new instance each time you add or modify an item, leaving the original intact, with `var b=ImmutableList<int>.Empty,AddRange(a).Remove(3)`. You can use LINQ to filter the items and create a new List (probably the most expensive way) with `var b=a.Where(x=>x!=3).ToList();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson what is vague is asking for the `best` way. It's quite possible the best is to create an `ImmutableList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, if such operations are common.

Comment: Oh right. Somehow I missed that bit - need to clean my glasses :)

Comment: Incidentally, `var b=a.Where(x=>x!=3).ToList();` doesn't do what the OP wants because it removes ALL instances of 3 rather than just the first one.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I need to *get* glasses. I keep missing more and more details lately. I though the OP wanted to remove the item `3`

Comment: To be fair, the example doesn't include multiple instances of 3, which would be a better example.

Comment: Do you want to remove an item from the last position or from any arbitrary place?

Comment: Can you confirm: Do you want to remove only the first matching instance of the element (which is what `List<T>.Remove()` does as per your example) or do you want to remove ALL elements. The answer to that is very important!

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems to better match to [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.remove).

```
var a = ImmutableList.Create(1, 2, 3);
var b = a.Remove(2);

// Output: 1, 2, 3
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));

// Output: 1, 3
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));
```

Answer (score 1):

A list can be duplicated using the list constructor.

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = new List<int>(a);

b.Remove(3);

Console.WriteLine($"a has {a.Count} items");  // 3
Console.WriteLine($"b has {b.Count} items");  // 2
```

[dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UgE03y)

Note that this is a **shallow** copy. When dealing with reference types, you will have two separate lists who point at *the same* instances.

Comment: You mean `b.Remove(3)` not `a.Remove(3)`. OP doesn't want to change `a`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: My answer is consistent between which list gets shortened and the list counts you see in the end, there's no error here. But I'll swap it around to mirror the original example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Linq Except:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = a.Except(new int[]{3}).ToList();
```

Comment: That removes ALL instances of 3. but the OP is using `List<int>.Remove(3)` which only removes the first instance. So if the list was `1, 2, 3, 3` you would get a different result. That might be what the OP actually wants, but it depends if they understand what List<int>.Remove() does.